# If my datastore transaction fails, will code after the transaction run?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

What happens if my datastore transaction fails and I have some more code that is supposed to run after it finishes? Does the application throw and error and end there? Will my second block of code run or will it never be reached?

```
ofy().transact(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Some code here.
    }
});

// Some more datastore code here. Will this be reached if the transact fails?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the transaction fails you will get an exception. If you don't handle the exception it will propagate.

Comment: I'm not sure if even handling the exception would achieve anything.  In a transaction, all puts succeed or fail.  If you have a failed put, I don't think you could later succeed with another put, but not sure about that.

Comment: There are all sorts of reasons your unit of work can fail, and broad as the possible reasons for exceptions to be thrown. Your code can throw exceptions, maybe some remote call you're making will produce an exception, maybe the datastore will timeout, maybe some other call will timeout... who knows. How you handle them is up to you.

Comment: @stickfigure By "handle the exception" you mean catching it with a try-catch block right? So if I catch it inside the transaction that way, `// Some more datastore code here` will run?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Try/catch is a standard Java idiom that works in very predictable ways... this doesn't sound like an objectify or datastore specific question? I am happy to help but you'll need to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @stickfigure My question in the above comment is more of a Java question. I think you answered it though. I just want to make sure that if I save two entities in a transaction and that saving fails, an exception will be thrown that stops any further execution of code that may come after `// Some more datastore code here`

Comment: If you throw an exception, any code after the throw will not be executed (unless the exception is explicitly caught, or a finally block exists). But keep in mind that you can still get an exception thrown by the datastore when you try to commit, after your code block has executed. Transactions only guarantee that a unit of work either succeeds together, or fails together (and specifically with respect to datastore operations - your code could always make state changes in resources that are not part of the transaction).